# Getting undefined when submitting form using ngForm

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-5

Apologies if this has already been asked but after searching the web for a long time, I am still unable to find an answer to this. I am new to Angular and Typescripting and maybe it's a small thing I'm doing wrong but it's not working for me, so any help will be appreciated. Here is the problem,

I have a modal popup window with 2 inputs in it, when I click on the Save button, using ngForm I am unable to pass the values over to the save method. Here is my code, can you please advise what I'm doing wrong here,

**asset.component.html**

```
<ng-template #content let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header row d-flex justify-content-between mx-1 mx-sm-3 mb-0 pb-0 border-0">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Add Asset</h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form #asset = 'ngForm' (ngSubmit)="saveAsset(asset.value)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <h4><label for="assetId" class="form-label text-right" style="margin: 10pt"><b>Asset Name</b></label></h4>
                <input id="assetId" name="assetId" class="form-control element-text" list="assetDatalistOptions"
                       (change)="getAssetValue()" placeholder="Enter Asset Name ... " ngModel>
                <datalist id="assetDatalistOptions">
                    <option *ngFor="let asset of assets" value="{{asset.data_dictionary_entry.text}}">
                        {{asset.data_dictionary_entry.id}}-{{asset.data_dictionary_entry.text}}
                    </option>
                </datalist>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <h4><label for="airText" style="margin: 10pt"><b>Asset Information Requirement</b></label></h4>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="airText" name="airText" class="form-control element-text" placeholder="Enter AIR Text ... " ngModel>
                </div>

                <h4><label for="assetAirContent" style="margin: 10pt"><b>Linked AIR</b></label></h4>
                <div class="form=group" *ngFor="let asset of assets">
                    <ul *ngFor="let air of asset.airs" id="assetAirContent" class="list-group-horizontal-md">
                        <li *ngIf="asset.data_dictionary_entry.text === selectedAssetText &&  asset.airs.length>0" class="list-inline element-text">{{air}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" (click)="modal.close('Cancel')">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</ng-template>
```

**asset.component.ts**

```
assets: Array<Asset> = [];
saveAsset(asset: Asset): void {
        console.log("Saving Asset : ",asset);
        this.assetService.save(asset)
            .subscribe(asset => this.assets.push(asset));
    }
```

**asset.ts**

```
export interface Asset {
    id: string;
    data_dictionary_entry: DataDictionaryEntry
    airs: string[];
}
```

I hope I've covered all the code (I've taken out in between code to keep question short), one thing to note, inside **asset.component.html**, I'm trying to pass the values of input field s with IDs **assetId** and **airText**
Any help is greatly appreciated, Thank you and looking forward to hearing some good advice.

**EDIT:**

The **undefined** I get is as shown in the picture, I've updated the code to see what is being selected before I send it over which can be seen in the **JSON** I'm printing on the form page. Inside **saveAsset**, I'm creating an alert to show **asset.id** on the screen.
[image: Undefined alert]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I've finally figured out my fault and to be honest it was quite a **stupid** one, so basically this is what I was doing wrong,
I was sending **assetId** and **airText **in the form but under **saveAsset** method, I was trying to print **id** since asset had id there, so I changed the name field to **id** and **text** and now I am getting values to print.

Thank you to all who read and replied in my help.

Answer (score 0):

With a re-produced problem (e.g stackblitz) I could actually test the problem but my suspicion is that `(ngSubmit)="saveAsset(asset.value)"` on `<form>` doesn't get triggered? Does `saveAsset()` get called currently? Either way I refactored this to the `Save` button.

```html
 <div class="modal-header row d-flex justify-content-between mx-1 mx-sm-3 mb-0 pb-0 border-0">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Add Asset</h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form #asset = 'ngForm'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h4><label for="assetId" class="form-label text-right" style="margin: 10pt"><b>Asset Name</b></label></h4>
                <input id="assetId" name="assetId" class="form-control element-text" list="assetDatalistOptions"
                       (change)="getAssetValue()" placeholder="Enter Asset Name ... " ngModel>
                <datalist id="assetDatalistOptions">
                    <option *ngFor="let asset of assets" value="{{asset.data_dictionary_entry.text}}">
                        {{asset.data_dictionary_entry.id}}-{{asset.data_dictionary_entry.text}}
                    </option>
                </datalist>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <h4><label for="airText" style="margin: 10pt"><b>Asset Information Requirement</b></label></h4>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="airText" name="airText" class="form-control element-text" placeholder="Enter AIR Text ... " ngModel>
                </div>

                <h4><label for="assetAirContent" style="margin: 10pt"><b>Linked AIR</b></label></h4>
                <div class="form=group" *ngFor="let asset of assets">
                    <ul *ngFor="let air of asset.airs" id="assetAirContent" class="list-group-horizontal-md">
                        <li *ngIf="asset.data_dictionary_entry.text === selectedAssetText &&  asset.airs.length>0" class="list-inline element-text">{{air}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" (click)="saveAsset(asset.value)" type="button">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" (click)="modal.close('Cancel')">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Joosep, yes saveAsset() method is called, I do see the console.log output, but for asset value, I see eihter Empty or Undefined message, no matter what changes I make.

Comment: Maybe this might help ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mmacyc?file=src/app/app.component.ts ... well I haven't added the css or other little bit code but now it's doing exactly what I'm experiencing.