# Angular - form makes other elements unreadable

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms

I have a page to maintain all the users of the application. In this application you first see a list of all user. When you click on the user you see details and have the option to change/delete. This works fine. Than I add an extra part to add users  'voeg gebruiker toe'. This contains a form. When I added the form, suddenly the pag is unable to read the properties of users. Though it is still taking them in, which you can see by the correct number of bulletpoints that are created. I have found 2 topics which had a similar error:

1. [core.mjs:6484 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72132655/core-mjs6484-error-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-nam)
2. [Getting undefined when submitting form using ngForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71451566/getting-undefined-when-submitting-form-using-ngform)

But both topics refer to  a problem caused by not using *NgIf. But this can not be my problem, since the list should just be generated when the page is created and is not depending on a selected user. If I do add (*ngIf="users"), the page doesn't show any list anymore. I cannot see how my form interfers with the findAll() code. I would very much appreciate not having to have to make another component for it. So I need to solve it another way.

screenshot of output:

[image]

Below you can find my html en component:

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserZnPass } from 'src/app/model/UserZnPass';
import { User } from '../../model/User';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  users!:User[];
  selectedUser!: User;
  newUser!: UserZnPass;

  onClick(user:User): void {
    this.selectedUser = user;
  }

  constructor(private userService:UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(user => { this.users = user});
  }

  add(): void {
    if(!
      this.newUser.naam.trim() || this.newUser.voornaam.trim() || this.newUser.email.trim() ||
      this.newUser.role.trim()) { return;}
      this.userService.addUser({
        naam: this.newUser.naam, voornaam: this.newUser.voornaam, email: this.newUser.email, 
        role: "ROLE_" + this.newUser.role.toUpperCase()
      } as UserZnPass)
          .subscribe(user => { 
              this.users.push(user);
              this.newUser = {} as User;
            });
  
  }

}
```

html

```
<h1>Users</h1>

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let user of users" (click)="onClick(user)">{{user.naam}} {{user.voornaam}}
    </li>
    
</ul>
<app-user-detail [user]="selectedUser"></app-user-detail>


<h2>Voeg gebruiker toe</h2>

<div>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>naam:
                <input [(ngModel)]="newUser.naam" name="userNaam">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>voornaam:
                <input [(ngModel)]="newUser.voornaam" name="userVoornaam">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>email:
                <input [(ngModel)]="newUser.email" name="userEmail">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>role:
                <select>
                    <option [(ngModel)]="newUser.role" value="USER">User</option>
                    <option [(ngModel)]="newUser.role" value="ADMIN">Admin</option>
                </select>
            </label>     
        </div> 
             <button class="btn" (click)="add()">Toevoegen</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the `newUser`:

```
 constructor(private userService:UserService) {
   this.newUser = new UserZnPass();
 }
```

Inside html you can check if newUser is null:

```
*ngIf="newUser"
```

Comment: that worked, and as you say it I understand why it needs to happen, I mark as correct when I can